# What latest change in Maps API could cause markers to shift right and disappear?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, svg, google-maps-api-3

I checked up on a Maps app I made and found that my markers had shifted over, and only displays in Chrome when the page is zoomed out. Polygons render fine, but the markers do not render anymore in Firefox and are shifted in Chrome (when they do appeaer).

In the screenshot, you can see the markers are no longer above Manhattan as they should be.

[image: Shifted markers in Chrome]

What recent change to the Maps API could have caused this? I looked through the release notes in these past few months and nothing seems to apply to this sudden shift.

Here is a snippet of how I create markers:

```
$.each(data[i], function(key, val){
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(val.lat, val.long);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      icon: {
        url: markerIcon,
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(30,30),
      },
      map: map,
  });
  markers.push(marker);
});
```

I have tried specifying the release (3.25) and frozen (3.24) versions, but get the same problem. I've been using experimental (not specifying a version) and the markers loaded in their proper places a few months ago.

**EDIT:**

I figured out it is a problem with using SVGs as my markers.
`markerIcon` in `url: markerIcon,` is a path to a SVG file. The problem is fixed if I use a PNG or JPG file.

Investigating using Symbols for my SVGs instead. Still not sure what changes in Chrome, Firefox or Maps API would cause this new bug.

Answer (score 1):

Updating my marker to use a Symbol to hold SVG information instead of linking to a SVG file worked:

```
      var transparentCircle = {
        path: 'M-5,0a5,5 0 1,0 10,0a5,5 0 1,0 -10,0',
        fillColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        scale: 1,
        strokeWeight: 0
      };

      ...
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          icon: transparentCircle,
          map: map,
      });
```

However, still not sure what changes in Chrome, FF, or Maps API broke the original SVG setup.